# Telescope focal length, reducer and/or Barlow

Tags: telescope, optics

Say I have a scope with a given diameter $D$, a given focal length $f$, and a given exit barrel diameter $B$. It has a maximum true FoV of $B/f$ (supposing $B<<f$).

Would adding a 0.5x focal reducer exactly amount to having a $D/(f/2)$ scope with barrel size $B$, for all intends and purposes (i.e. be optically indistinguishable from an actual scope of diameter $D$ and $f/2$ focal length) ? I feel like it should, but I'm unsure whether maximum true FoV would indeed become $2B/f$ as on a "natural" $D/(f/2)$ scope.

(You may ignore light absorption from the focal reducer' lens(es))

Conversely, say I have the same initial scope with a given diameter $D$, a given focal length $f$, and a given exit barrel diameter $B$ (it still has a maximum true FoV of $B/f$ (supposing $B<<f$)).

Would adding a 2x Barlow exactly amount to having a $D/(2f)$ scope with barrel size $B$, for all intends and purposes (i.e. be optically indistinguishable from an actual scope of diameter $D$ and $2f$ focal length) ?

Comment: Other things like added chromatic and other aberrations should be ignored as well?

Comment: I'm interested in those aspects as well, but maybe as a separate addendum. I'd like to first know the answer for a perfect optical system (still subject to physical limits such as resolution due to aperture, etc.). Then, if some aberrations happen to be doubled or not or whatever, that can be indicated as well I guess.